# XSLT - format comma seperated list into table format

Tags: xslt

A web service is returning a list of persons in the below xml format. The values are seperated by a semicolon. I need to display the values in 2 or 3 columns (Needs to be a variable).

Desired Results:

```
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>Smith, John</td>
  <td>Jackson, Samuel</td>
  <td>Wayne, Bruce</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Cosby, Bill</td>
  <td>Kent, Clarke</td>
  <td>Leno, Jay</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>OBrian, Conan</td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Xml sample

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PI>Smith, John; Jackson,
 Samuel; Wayne, Bruce; Cosby, Bill; Kent, Clarke; Leno, Jay; OBrian,
 Conan; </PI>
```

Comment: Can you use XSLT2 or are you limited to XSLT1?

Comment: I'm stuck with XSLT1. So its not as easy to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please accept Holman's solution. His technique is spot-on.

### XSLT 2.0 Solution

Your sample input data suggests semicolon terminated list, rather than a semicolon separated list.

This XSLT 2.0 stylesheet will work correctly with either a semicolon terminated list or a semicolon separated  list. It takes one input parameter `col-count`, which defaults to 3.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:param name="col-count" select="3" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
 <table border="1">
  <xsl:variable name="names" select="tokenize(.,';')[normalize-space(.)]" />
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$names , for $x in 1 to
    ($col-count - (count($names) mod $col-count)) mod $col-count return ''"
                      group-by="(position() - 1) idiv $col-count"> 
   <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
     <td><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" /></td>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </tr>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Notes:

(1) Notice the brevity of the solution, and the absence of clumsy `xsl:if` statements. The use of calculated sequences (as opposed to input document node selections), is not just limited to the group-by attribute, but can also to applied to `select`. The use of computed sequences suggests a more functional view, rather than a procedural view.

(2) If you want the output to be safe for old browsers, then replace ...

```
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$names , for $x in 1 to
    ($col-count - (count($names) mod $col-count)) mod $col-count return ''"
                      group-by="(position() - 1) idiv $col-count">
```

... with ...

```
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$names , for $x in 1 to
    ($col-count - (count($names) mod $col-count)) mod $col-count return '&#160;'"
                      group-by="(position() - 1) idiv $col-count">
```

---

### XSLT 1.0 Solution

If you are stuck on XSLT 1.0, then you could use this equivalent, but less efficient stylesheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:esl="http://exslt.org/common"
  xmlns:so="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066463"
  version="1.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl so esl">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:variable name="col-count" select="3" /><!-- Must be 2 or 3. -->

<xsl:variable name="empty-rtf">
  <so:name>&#160;</so:name>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="empty" select="esl:node-set($empty-rtf)/*" />


<xsl:template match="/*">
  <table border="1">
    <xsl:variable name="names-rtf">
      <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="." />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="names" select="esl:node-set($names-rtf)/*" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$names[(position() mod $col-count) = 1]">
      <xsl:variable name="row" select="position() - 1" />
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$names[floor((position() - 1) div $col-count) = $row]" />
        <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
         <xsl:for-each select="($names|$empty)[position() &lt;=
                               (($col-count - (count($names) mod $col-count)) mod $col-count)]">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="$empty" />
         </xsl:for-each>  
        </xsl:if>  
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>  
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="split">
  <xsl:param name="list" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($list,';')">
      <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-before($list,';')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list,';')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>  
    <xsl:when test="normalize-space($list)">
      <so:name><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($list)" /></so:name>
    </xsl:when>  
    <xsl:otherwise />
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="so:*" priority="2">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. I'm stuck with XSLT 1 but that solution works great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 solution with the number of columns as a variable as requested.  This employs a technique I teach in the classroom that underscores that grouping need not be by values in the XML (as many XSLT users assume), rather, it can be by any arbitrary calculation (in this case, the result of division).

*[edited to show multiple invocations with different number of columns]*

```
t:\ftemp>type names.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PI>Smith, John; Jackson,
Samuel; Wayne, Bruce; Cosby, Bill; Kent, Clarke; Leno, Jay; OBrian,
Conan; </PI>
t:\ftemp>call xslt2 names.xml names.xsl names.out.xml "cols=3" 

t:\ftemp>type names.out.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>Smith, John</td>
      <td>Jackson, Samuel</td>
      <td>Wayne, Bruce</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Cosby, Bill</td>
      <td>Kent, Clarke</td>
      <td>Leno, Jay</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>OBrian, Conan</td>
      <td/>
      <td/>
   </tr>
</table>

t:\ftemp>call xslt2 names.xml names.xsl names.out.xml "cols=2" 

t:\ftemp>type names.out.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>Smith, John</td>
      <td>Jackson, Samuel</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Wayne, Bruce</td>
      <td>Cosby, Bill</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Kent, Clarke</td>
      <td>Leno, Jay</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>OBrian, Conan</td>
      <td/>
   </tr>
</table>

t:\ftemp>type names.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="cols" required="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="PI">
  <table border="1">
    <!--determine population and group by number of columns-->
    <xsl:for-each-group select="tokenize(.,';\s+')"
                        group-by="(position()-1) idiv $cols">
      <tr>
        <!--put members into the row-->
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
          </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!--filler for the last row-->
        <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
          <xsl:for-each select="count(current-group())+1 to $cols">
            <td/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem
```

Comment: @g-ken-holman: The OP's input sample suggests the input data is semicolon terminated, even though the text of this question says semicolon separated. If the OP means semicolon terminated (which is more likely than not), then your stylesheet will produce the wrong results when the count of names evenly divides by the column count.

Comment: Granted.  Adding the `[normalize-space()]` predicate would toss the last entry.  Thank you for pointing that out.